# Will .save() data from Api directly to db be faster than sending it from a Django form?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, api

I am pulling a lot of data from an API to my django template and I keep getting a 504 timeout error so it never finishes. I can cut the data I am calling in half and it prints just fine.

Will I get any error if I pull the data from the api and save it to my db straight from my view??

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question and the answer depends on different factors.
Obviously forms adding some additional overhead to response time, but it can be a very small agains the transaction overhead and tryouts of reducing it may not solve your problem.

Firs thing I'll advice to do in this situation is to use [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to analize queries completion time vs response complete time.

Next, you may want to answer this question - can I optimize queries to reduce transaction commit time? Maybethere is an redundant extra validation that is taking to long?

Finally, when you realize that data saving process can't be done within comfort time, you can take a look to the way of doing the transaction in asynchronous maner using [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) tasks.